# How to get rid of file name on download on website?

Tags: html

I've named this file originally sweaty resume, but now have changed it, and its still showing up as sweaty resume. How do I change it?

[image]

```
    <h1 id="resume" data-aos="zoom-in-down" data-aos-duration="750">Resume</h1>
    <div id="resume-container">
        <div data-aos="zoom-in-down" data-aos-duration="750" class="resume-inner-container">
            <embed src="./Resume/Resume.pdf" width="80%" height="600px" value="Resume">
        </div>
        <a data-aos="zoom-in-down" data-aos-duration="750" href="Resume/Resume.pdf"
            target="_blank" download>
            Download
            Me!</a>
    </div>
```

I would see a glimpse of the Resume.pdf and then it would change back to sweaty resume, how would I go about this?

Comment: Maybe a caching problem? Does a Ctrl+F5 (Hard refresh) solves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your PDF document's title and not the filename.

You have to change it in the editor where you created it (MS word for example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-21d604c2-481e-4379-8e54-1dd4622c6b75)

Or you can use some tools to change the title in the document metadata, some of them are available online (just google "Edit PDF Metadata").

---

Before doing that, make sure that the file is not being cached, probably you renamed the file from its editor correctly and you are just seeing a cached version, so from your network tab see if the file is being fetched from the network and not being loaded from the cache. If it's the case do a hard-refresh `Ctrl (Control) + Shift and click R` or look it up for your browser/OS